# Where is the mistake? Finding majority

Tags: java

I want to find the majority in array (number that appears most of the time).
I have a sorted array and use these cycles:

```
for(int k = 1;k < length;k++)
{
    if(arr[k-1] == arr[k])
    {
        count++;
        if(count > max)
        {
            max = count;
            maxnum = arr[k-1];
        }
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

or

```
for(int h=0;h<length;h++)
{
    for(int l=1;l<length;l++)
    {
        if(arr[h] == arr[l])
        {
            count++;
            if(count > max)
            {
                max = count;
                maxnum = arr[h];
            }
        } else count = 0;
    }
}
```

they are similiar. When i try them on small arrays everything seems to be ok. But on a long run array with N elements 0<=N<=500000, each element K 0<=K<=10^9 they give wrong answers. 
Here is solution with mistake http://ideone.com/y2gvnX. I know there are better algos to find majority but i just need to know where is my mistake.

I really can't find it :( Will really appreciate help!

Comment: In the second one, the second `for` loop's counter should probably start at `h`, not `1`.

Comment: Your first algo is much more efficient than the second and they are not equivalent. The first one looks ok the second does not.

Comment: Your first code seems correct. The second approach seems designed for an unsorted array. It needs to reset `count` for each value of `h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first algorithm looks correct to me. The second one (which is what your linked code uses) needs some initialization each time through the loop. Also, the inner loop does not need to start at `1` each time; it can start at `h + 1`:

```
for(int h=0; h<length; h++)
{
    count = 1; // for the element at arr[h]
    for(int l=h + 1; l<length; l++)
    {
        if(arr[h] == arr[l])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count > max)
    {
        max = count;
        maxnum = arr[h];
    }
}
```

The first algorithm is much better for sorted arrays. Even for unsorted arrays, it would be cheaper to sort the array (or a copy of it) and then use the first algorithm rather than use the second.

Note that if there are ties (such as for the array `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` as per @Rohit's comment), this will find the first value (in the sort order) that has the maximum count.

Comment: @TedHopp.. You should also quote that this will not give correct result in case of : - [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]. It will only give `2` as max count. But it should give both `1` and `2`.

Comment: @RohitJain - Actually it will give 2 as the `max` count and will give 1 as the `maxnum`. But you're right--I will clarify that it will return the first max in the event of ties.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use the `first algorithm`, as your array is sorted. 2nd algorithm runs through the array twice unnecessarily.

Now your `first algorithm` is almost correct, but it has **two problems**: -

- The first problem is you are setting `count = 0`, in else part,
  rather it should be set to `1`. Because every element comes at least
  once.
- Secondly, you don't need to set `max` every time in your `if`. Just
  `increment count`, till the `if-condition` is satisfied, and as soon
  as `condition fails`, check for the `current count` with `current
  max`, and reset the current max accordingly.

This way, your `max` will not be checked on every iteration, but only when a *mismatch* is found.

So, you can try out this code: -

```
    // initialize `count = 1`, and `maxnum = Integer.MIN_VALUE`.
    int count = 1;
    int max = 0;
    int maxnum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for(int k = 1;k < length;k++)
     {
         if(arr[k-1] == arr[k]) {
              count++;   // Keep on increasing count till elements are equal

         } else {
             // if Condition fails, check for the current count v/s current max

             if (max < count) {   // Move this from `if` to `else`
                 max = count;
                 maxnum = arr[k - 1];
             }
             count = 1;  // Reset count to 1. As every value comes at least once.
         }
     }
```

**Note : -**

The problem with this approach is, if two numbers say - `1` and `3`, comes equal number of times - which is max, then the `max` count will be counted for `3` (assuming that `3` comes after `1`, and `maxnum` will contain `3` and ignore `1`. But they both should be considered.

So, basically, you cannot use a `for loop` and maintain a `count` to take care of this problem.

A better way is to create a `Map<Integer, Integer>`, and store the count of each value in there. And then later on `sort` that `Map` on `value`.

Comment: Thanks! I used map, but it is takes much more memory. Otherwise it is better.

Comment: @Will_code_4_food.. Then in that case don't store all the int, count mapping in it. Just store the int value with current Max count, and update it, when max changes And if you find two value with same max value, store both of them. You would need to use this approach, to ensure that you get correct result in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your first algorithm only makes sense if the array is sorted.

Your second algorithm just sets count to zero in the wrong place. You want to set count to zero before you enter the inner `for` loop.

```
 for(int h=0;h<length;h++)
 {
  count = 0;
  for(int l=0;l<length;l++)
  {
   if(arr[h] == arr[l])
   {
    count++;
    if(count > max)
    {
     max = count;
     maxnum = arr[h];
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Also, you don't need to check `count` each time in the inner loop.

```
 max = 0;
 for(int h=0;h<length;h++)
 {
  count = 0;
  for(int l=0;l<length;l++)
  {
   if(arr[h] == arr[l])
    count++;
  }
  if(count > max)
  {
   max = count;
   maxnum = arr[h];
  }
 }
```

Comment: The first algorithm makes perfect sense for a sorted array (equal values will be contiguous).

Comment: Thanks! First algo is correct, but second does not pass the test (i check at http://acm.timus.ru/submit.aspx?space=1&num=1510).

Answer (score 0):

The error I can readily see is that if all elements are distinct, then the max at end is 0.
However it has to be 1.
So when you update count in "else" case, update it to 1 instead of 0, as a new element has been discovered, and its count is 1.